# Broken PMU hardware detected, using software events only

Tags: linux, hardware-failure, dmesg

I have two out of four machines (dell r815) that are not showing the cpu hardware counters when I run (from linux-tools-common on ubuntu or debian):

```
perf list
```

I used strace and found out the problem was that /sys/devices/cpu is missing on the two machines with the problem. I traced this back to an error in dmesg:

```
Performance Events: Broken PMU hardware detected, using software events only.
```

On the machines that work it says

```
Performance Events: AMD PMU driver.
```

My question is: what can I do to make sure this isn't just a software or configuration problem? To me it looks like it might be bad hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem was that the microcode version on the CPUs for the affected machines was older. I tried installing the package amd64-microcode which did update the microcode but only after the PMU error had already shown up in dmesg. I used Dell's bootable server configuration tool to update the bios and system firmware and it fixed the problem. Hopefully this will be helpful to anyone else who runs into the same problem.